# How to translate Array<T?> to List<T>?

Tags: kotlin

I tried this:

```
fun <T> computeMyThing(): List<T> {
    val array: Array<T?> = computeArray()
    return array.toList()
}
```

But, unsurprisingly, it won't compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're sure that no nulls are in the array you can use a cast:

```
array.toList() as List<T>
```

<del>If there are in fact nulls you need to filter them out:</del>

```
array.filter { it != null } as List<T>
```

<del>As you can see, you still need to cast though. You can also write an extension methods that filters out nulls and returns the correct type:</del>

```
fun <T> Array<T?>.filterNotNull(): List<T> {
    val destination = arrayListOf<T>()
    for (element in this) {
        if (element != null) {
            destination.add(element)
        }
    }
    return destination
}
```

<del>Then you can use it like so:</del>

```
array.filterNotNull()
```

Edit: There is already a `filterNotNull` method in Kotlin. The IDE didn't suggest it because there is a problem with the type parameter `T`. `T` and `T?` are both nullable. To fix it, change the method signature to `fun <T : Any> computeMyThing(): List<T>` and you will be able to use `array.filterNotNull()` without declaring it yourself.

Comment: There are [plans](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-4410) to add a `mapNotNull` method which you should be able to use for just filtering nulls.

Comment: @Suseika Please see my edit. You don't need to declare `filterNotNull` yourself.